# REGEX IF THEN ELSE Statement

Tags: regex

I've got a need to write a regular expression that has me scratching my head. Essentially I have a column of data that includes values such as:

```
ACME Corp 123
Corp 742 ACME
Random Text
Broadway 1785 FB
```

What I want to do is look for the term `ACME` and `BROADWAY`. If either exists, keep that and only that. If neither exists, keep the entire string. So that column above would turn in to:

```
ACME
ACME
Random Text
Broadway
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you hardstuck on using regex? Any other alternatives for parsing that would make life easier like Python?

Comment: This would be a lot easier with `if` `elif` and `else` statements from whatever you're working on than doing it with Regex. Is there any particular reason why you need to use pure regex? What language is your code in?

Comment: If you have a list of entities (in your case, companies, it looks like), that you want to extract, why not just check whether they're present in the string? Like `if 'ACME' in 'ACME Corp 123'`...

Comment: I could very easily do this as a CASE STATEMENT in SQL and it would be done in 5 seconds. However, this particular toolset I'm using restricts me to REGEX.

Comment: Nashville guy, huh?

Answer (score 26):

### Brief

This one had me scratching my head for a bit. I'm sure regex alone is not the best solution to this problem, however, here is your solution.

---

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/F34Be0/1)

**Regex**

```
^.*?((?(?=.*?(\b(?:broadway|acme)\b).*?)\2|.*)).*?$
```

**Substitution**

Group 1 as below. You can instead gather group 1 variables from an array of matches, but if you want to replace, you can use the following

```
$1
```

---

### Results

**Note:** I added another string as a test to ensure if either word was placed midway through a line, it would still catch it.

#### Input

```
ACME Corp 123
Corp 742 ACME
Some ACME some
Random Text
Broadway 1785 FB
```

#### Output

```
ACME
ACME
ACME
Random Text
Broadway
```

---

### Explanation

Using the case-insensitive `i` and multi-line `m` flags:

- `^` Assert position at the beginning of the line
- `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `((?(?=.*?(\b(?:broadway|acme)\b).*?)\2|.*))` Broken into parts

  - `()` Capture the following

    - `(?(?=...))` If/else statement
    - `(?=.*?(\b(?:broadway|acme)\b).*?)` Positive lookahead to match the following

      - `.*?` Any character any number of times, but as few as possible
      - `(...)` Capture the following into capture group 2
      - `\b(?:broadway|acme)\b` word boundary, followed by either `broadway` or `acme`, followed by a word boundary
      - `.*?` Any character any number of times, but as few as possible
    - `\2` If the if/else statement is **true** (it matches the above), capture the group (as described above) - which is simply `broadway` or `acme`
    - `.*` If the if/else statement is **false**, match any character any number of times
- `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

—-

## Update

Since my answer has garnered decent attention, I figured I should revise it. Not sure if the attention is for if/else in regex or if it relates more to the OP’s expected results from sample input.

#### if/else

I should mention that the general format for regex if/else is as follows (and that only certain regex engines support this tag):

```
(?(?=condition)x|y)
```

In the above regex (?=condition) can be pretty much whatever you want (you can also use negative lookaheads or lookbehinds, even combinations thereof.

#### Alternatives

As if/else in regex isn’t supported in all languages, you may be able to use a workaround:

```
# optional group, fallback to match all (x?y)
^(?:.*?\b(broadway|acme)\b)?.*

# alternation (x||y)
^(?:.*?\b(broadway|acme)\b|.*)

# tempered greedy token alternation
^(?:(?!\b(?:broadway|acme)\b).|(broadway|acme))+

# same as above reusing capture group 1’s definition 
^(?:(?!\b(broadway|acme)\b).|((?1)))+
```

Comment: Beautiful approach. Good to know there is someone around who can teach us some chomps. :)

Answer (score 4):

A regex that will be sufficient to solve this problem is:

```
 ^(?(?=(acme|broadway))\1|[\w\s])+?$
```

Why is this sufficient? If either `acme` or `broadway` are in your input string, then group 1 will capture that value. If group 1 is empty, the full match is your result.

breakdown:

```
 ^(?                          # start conditional
    (?=                       # lookahead for position before
      (                       # group 1 start
        acme|broadway         # either "acme" or "broadway"
      )                       # group 1 end
    )
    \1                        # if found, then match group 1
    |                         # else
    [\w\s]                    # read a word char or space
  )+?$                        # do this over and over again, non-greedy
```

Take a look at it at [example 1](https://regex101.com/r/6KZ81f/1)

Comment: No. Take a closer look. Or look at this: https://regex101.com/r/6KZ81f/3

Comment: your regex seems invalid.

Comment: A bit more context pls. If you're stating that the regex is invalid, I would suggest checking the links. If your statement is 'this doesn't answer the OP's question', explain why you think so.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution *without* using *lookahead assertions*

```
^.*(ACME|Broadway).*$
```

Explanation:

```
^                     # beginning of the string
 .*                   # match any character any number of times
   (                  # start of capture group
    ACME|Broadway     # if the input string has ACME or Broadway capture in the memory($1)
   )                  # end of the capture group
 .*                   # match any character any number of times
$                     # end of the string
```

https://regex101.com/r/mDCL5g/1

Additionally you can use the same regex in **Javascript** like below

```
'ACME Corp 123'.replace(/^.*(ACME|Broadway).*$/, '$1');    // ACME
'Corp 742 ACME'.replace(/^.*(ACME|Broadway).*$/, '$1');    // ACME
'Random Text'.replace(/^.*(ACME|Broadway).*$/, '$1');      // Random Text
'Broadway 1785 FB'.replace(/^.*(ACME|Broadway).*$/, '$1'); // Broadway
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another attempt:

```
(?:^.*)(ACME)(?:.*$)?|(?:^.*)(Broadway)(?:.*$)|^.*$
```

And the regex [code in use](https://regex101.com/r/emyowz/1).

It's close to Marc Lambrichs solution, but uses two capturing groups (which is arguably worse - but it depends on your needs). If none of the two groups ($1 or $2) has a match you will find the Random Text in the full match.

If you do not like the second capturing group you can try this:

```
(?:^.*?)(ACME|Broadway)(?:.*$)?|^.*?$
```

Or if you would like to have everything in $1 like in ctwheels solution:

```
(?(?=(?:^.*?)?(ACME|Broadway)(?:.*$)?)\1|(^.*?$))
```

As pointed out by Marc, a plus of my approach is that it does not require advanced features that are not available in all regex engines.
However, [conditional Regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html), as used in the third regex, are not available everywhere.

Comment: Yes, it's worse. Because now you have to check both group 1 and 2 to know if you don't have a match. In all situations.

Comment: As I have said. I could have adjusted it, but since we do not have any response from the OP I felt it would be pointless, anyways.