# Python regex matching group with multi-layer conditions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this regex :

```
cont_we_re = r"((?!\S+\s?(?:(cbf|cd3|cbm|m3|m[\\\>\?et]?|f3|ft3)))(?:([0-9,\.]+){2,})(?:\s*(?:(lb|kg)\.?s?))?)"
```

Right now, the logic followed is match with any numeric chunk optionally if followed by only `kgs` or `lbs` but don't match if `cbf`, `cd3`, `cbm`, `m3` etc. are found after the numeric chunk. It works perfectly for these sample cases :

```
s1 = "18300 kg 40344.6 lbs 25000 m3"
s2 = "18300kg 40344.6lbs 25000m3"
s3 = "18300 kg   KO"
s4 = "40344.6 lb5   "
s5 = "40344.6  "
```

I'm using `re.finditer()` with `re.IGNORECASE` flag, like this :

```
for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]:
    all_val = [i.group().strip() for i in re.finditer(cont_we_re, s, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Gives me this output :

```
['18300 kg', '40344.6 lbs']
['18300kg', '40344.6lbs']
['18300 kg']
['40344.6 lb']
['40344.6']
```

Now I'm trying to implement another logic : if we find numeric chunk followed by `lbs` then match it with first priority and return only that match, but if not found `lbs` and found only numeric chunk or numeric chunk followed by `kgs` then take those.

I've done this without changing the regex, like this :

```
for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]:
    all_val = [i.group().strip() for i in re.finditer(cont_we_re, s, re.IGNORECASE)]
    kg_val = [i for i in all_val if re.findall(r"kg\.?s?", i)]
    lb_val = [i for i in all_val if re.findall(r"lb\.?s?", i)]
    final_val = lb_val if lb_val else (kg_val if kg_val else list(set(all_val) - (set(kg_val+lb_val))))
```

This gives me the desired output (which is perfect) :

```
['40344.6 lbs']
['40344.6lbs']
['18300 kg']
['40344.6 lb']
['40344.6']
```

Question is how can I apply this same logic in the regex, without finding for `kgs` and `lbs` separately on each matched group by `cont_we_re` for each string. I tried "IF-THEN-ELSE" type regex as portrayed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432854/regex-if-then-else-statement) but it doesn't work as the first part of the regex `(?` supposedly yields pattern error in python. Is there any way to do this with only `cont_we_re` regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using the [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) might be making use of [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) and lookarounds to check for the presence of `lb`

```
(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?lbs?|(?<!lb.*)(?!.*lb)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: kg)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?kg(*SKIP)(*FAIL))
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?lbs?` Match the number format with an optional decimal part followed by lb and optional s
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<!lb.*)(?!.*lb)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: kg)?` Assert that the string does not contain `lb`, then match the number format with an optional decimal part followed by `kg`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?kg(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Match the number format followed by `kg` and skip that match
- `)` Close non capturing group

For example

```
import regex

s1 = "18300 kg 40344.6 lbs 25000 m3"
s2 = "18300kg 40344.6lbs 25000m3"
s3 = "18300 kg   KO"
s4 = "40344.6 lb5   "
s5 = "40344.6  "

cont_we_re = r"(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?lbs?|(?<!lb.*)(?!.*lb)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: kg)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?kg(*SKIP)(*FAIL))"


for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]:
    all_val = [i.group().strip() for i in regex.finditer(cont_we_re, s, regex.IGNORECASE)]
    print(all_val)
```

Output

```
['40344.6 lbs']
['40344.6lbs']
['18300 kg']
['40344.6 lb']
['40344.6']
```

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/PHGWV95866)

Answer (score 1):

This regex relies on a bunch of if-then-else tests supported by the `regex` package from the PyPI repository. It first looks  to see if the input string contains a number followed by `kg`. If it does if then matches the number and `kg` and the optional characters that may follow (`\.?\s`), though I believe this should be reversed according to standard English usage, for example `10kgs.` and not `10kg.s`). If it cannot find this match (here comes the else part), then it looks for a number followed by `lb` and then if successful it matches that. And finally, if that fails it just looks for a number. Perhaps not the most efficient way, but it works up to a point.

Test case `s6` shows that even though a `kg` amount follows a `lb` amount, it is selected anyway. Test case `s7` shows that numbers followed by `cbf`, for example, are ignored.

```
import regex as re

cont_we_re = r"""
        (?(?=.*?[0-9,.]{2,}\s*kg)
            .*?(?P<VAL>[0-9,.]{2,}\s*kg\.?s?)
            |
            .*?(?(?=.*?[0-9,.]{2,}\s*lb)
                (?P<VAL>[0-9,.]{2,}\s*lb\.?s?)
                |
                (?(?=[0-9,.]{2,}\s?(cbf|cd3|cbm|m3|m[\\\>\?et]?|f3|ft3))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?P<VAL>[0-9,.]{2,}))
            )
        )
        """

rex = re.compile(cont_we_re, flags=re.X|re.I)

s1 = "18300 kg 40344.6 lbs 25000 m3"
s2 = "18300kg 40344.6lbs 25000m3"
s3 = "18300 kg   KO"
s4 = "40344.6 lb5   "
s5 = "40344.6  "
s6 = "40344.6  128 LB.S 19kg"
s7 = "101.99 cbf  128"

vals = []
for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]:
    m = rex.search(s)
    vals.append(m['VAL'])
print(vals)
```

Prints:

```
['18300 kg', '18300kg', '18300 kg', '40344.6 lb', '40344.6', '19kg', '128']
```

**UPDATE**

I just realized that pounds (LB) are to take precedence over kilograms (KG), in which case the regex should be:

```
cont_we_re = r"""
        (?(?=.*?[0-9,.]{2,}\s*lb)
            .*?(?P<VAL>[0-9,.]{2,}\s*lb\.?s?)
            |
            .*?(?(?=.*?[0-9,.]{2,}\s*kg)
                (?P<VAL>[0-9,.]{2,}\s*kg\.?s?)
                |
                (?(?=[0-9,.]{2,}\s?(cbf|cd3|cbm|m3|m[\\\>\?et]?|f3|ft3))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?P<VAL>[0-9,.]{2,}))
            )
        )
        """
```

and the results:

```
['40344.6 lbs', '40344.6lbs', '18300 kg', '40344.6 lb', '40344.6', '128 LB.S', '128']
```